# PassportJS, Angular and jsonwebtokens

Tags: angularjs, express, token, passport.js, passport-facebook

I have an Express/Angular app with passportjs-facebook auth and I'm trying to implement a token based system to make calls to my api using jsonwebtokens and avoiding sessions/cookies.

The process that I had in mind goes as follows:

1. Anonymous user tries to log in with Facebook.
2. Facebook ID is checked
   against the DB retrieving the user if there's a match or creating a
   new one if the user doesn't exist.
3. A token is generated for that
   user.
4. Send token to user
5. Angular app gets token and stores it on localStorage.
6. An interceptor on the angular app checks for the user's token as sends it on a header for any subsequent calls.

I'm struggling with steps 4 and 5, I'm not sure how to pass the token and get it on my angular app. Could anyone point me on the right direction to get this working?

Answer (score 0):

You express app can generate the JWT for the app after FB auth.

Take look at this article: https://auth0.com/blog/2014/01/07/angularjs-authentication-with-cookies-vs-token/